# Customized 12.04.3 Ubuntu ISO fails to boot in Virtualbox -- getting stuck at the txt.cfg/Ubuntu boot screen

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm attempting to make a custom Ubuntu installer, but the ISOs that I'm generating fail to boot in VirtualBox 4.1.18.

The raw ISO (downloaded here: http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=server&bits=64&release=lts) will boot in virtualbox, but my custom ISO will not, getting stuck at the pre-boot screen that is generated by `txt.cfg` -- on which the contents of the txt.cfg are displayed.

This is a screenshot of what I'm seeing: [image: txt.cfg contents screen]

As a sanity test, I've tried to generate an ISO without a kickstart or preseed file to test if it's my changes that are causing it:

1. Mounted the iso as a loop device to /mnt/iso
2. `mkdir -p /opt/serveriso/`
3. `cp -rT /mnt/iso/. /opt/serveriso/.`
4. `cd /opt/serveriso`
5. `mkisofs -D -r -V 'UBUNTU_HARDWARE' -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o /opt/ubuntu_hardware.iso /opt/serveriso`

Can someone help me find out why Ubuntu is displaying the contents of my txt.cfg instead of running it?

edit: As I'm `cp`-ing from /mnt/iso, I assume that the issue lies in either VirtualBox or (more likely) my mkisofs line.

Comment: I suspect you would need to show use the full contents of your txt.cfg  Have you changed any any of the other isolinux config files?

Comment: Virtualbox is ***not*** enterprise-grade.  Don't use it as a production hypervisor.

Comment: @HopelessN00b yes, of course not.  I'm using it to test the ISO.

Comment: @Zoredache the txt.cfg is the default one -- the `cp` line is there to blow away any of my customizations.

Comment: Can you provide the full ISO that's giving you problems?

Comment: @hbdgaf this is the case with standard ubuntu 12.04.3 -- the initrd will be the standard one.

Comment: "I've tried to generate an ISO without a kickstart or preseed file to test if it's my changes that are causing it" What was the result of this test?

Comment: @sciurus I already solved the issue, but the result of that test was the same.  There was something about the splash screen that was making virtualbox unhappy.  Threw in a nosplash and everything was fine again  -- I didn't find the problem interesting enough to keep digging after getting a working fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `nosplash` to the end of txt.cfg and it seemed to solve the issue.

edit: The `lang` file didn't have a newline.  This was causing the installer to hang.